# alloy relation facts

Tags: alloy

Below is part of my work so far. I'm getting cycles and both ways connections in  between my Lines and single connections from Messages to Lines for some reason. I don't see why there are never more than one message to line connections. My facts are probably (most likely) a little wrong. Thanks for the help.

```
some sig Line{  
    nextLine: some Line,
}

sig Message{
    formedOfLines: Line,
}
fact MessageHasMoreThan1LineHasNextLine{
    all m:Message|#m.formedOfLines>1 implies #m.formedOfLines.nextLine>0
}
fact NoNextLineIsSelf
{
   all l1,l2:Line | l1=l2 implies l1.nextLine!=l2
}
fact LineBelongsToSomeMessage
{
    all l:Line | l in Message.formedOfLines
}
```

Comment: also, what kind of a fact can i add to make the Message sig see the nextLine as within its formedOfLines as well as the original Line. I can add a fact for the next line but then i will lose the original line. should i add another sig relation like first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model allows each `Line` to have multiple `nextLine`s, which might not be your intention.  That's why your `NoNextLineIsSelf` fact doesn't actually prevent loops, because `l.nextLine != l` can be true if `l.nextLine` contains more than one `Line` and one of them is `l`.  You can rewrite that fact to

```
all l: Line | l !in l.nextLine
```

to forbid all loops.

To forbid "two-way connections" between lines, you can write something like

```
all disj l1, l2: Line | l2 in l1.nextLine implies l1 !in l2.nextLine
```

(I'm not sure which one of your facts was supposed to do that)

If you want a `Message` to have more than 1 line, you should change the multiplicity of the `formedOfLines` to `set`, i.e.,

```
sig Message {
  formedOfLines: set Line
}
```

Comment: thanks, it takes some getting used to think properly for this.

Comment: btw, `all disj l1, l2: Line | l2 in l1.nextLine implies l1 !in l2.nextLine` breaks loops between each connection but not for more than 2 connection. There are cycles and loops still. I'm looking to find a solution

Comment: I didn't know you meant "loops" by "both ways connections"; I assumed it meant exactly what I wrote formally in Alloy.